# Use atom to open markdown files instead of gedit when I double click on markdown files

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, atom

On my computer I keep notes in markdown and I want when I double click on the icon through nautilus/filemanager on Ubuntu 16.04 to automatically open with Atom editor instead of gedit.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using Nautilus, choose any type of file you wanna open by default;
2. Right-click on it and chose "properties"
3. Go to "Open With" tab and chose your Atom;
4. Click on <kbd>set as default</kbd>.
   [image]